# Is that possible a multisig contract with ERC721?

Tags: solidity, erc-721, multisignature

I'm newbie in Solidity.
I was wondering if it's that possible to have a Multisignature contract with ERC721 standard.

I've found that simple example: https://github.com/christianlundkvist/simple-multisig

And I adapted it for what I need.
I would like to create a ERC721 smart contract that could be signed by two people.
I don't know if that could break ERC721 nature.

This is the code adapted from the Christian one:

In the next function is where one of the people that signs the contract is going to add the address:

```
function signature(address owners_) public {
    address lastAdd = address(0);
        isOwner[owners_] = true;
        lastAdd = owners_;
    ownersArr.push(owners_);
}
```

In the next one, is where the Contract is going to be created:

```
constructor() public ERC721Full("TwoPeopleAgreement", "TWOPEOPLEAGREEMENT") {
    owner = msg.sender;
}

function mint(
    People memory _people1,
    People memory _people2,
    Image memory _picture
) public payable {
    require(!_peopleExists[_people1.uuid]);
    require(!_peopleExists[_people2.uuid]);

    signature(msg.sender);
    require(ownersArr.length == 2);

    uint256 _id = peoples.push(_people1);
    uint256 _id2 = peoples.push(_people2);
    picture.push(_picture);
    _peopleExists[_people1.uuid] = true;
    _peopleExists[_people2.uuid] = true;

    nonce = nonce + 1;



    _mint(msg.sender, _id + _id2);
    sendtoOwner(msg.value);
}
```

Those are the structures:

```
contract TwoPeopleAgreement is ERC721Full {
  uint public nonce;            
  mapping (address => bool) isOwner;
  address[] public ownersArr;       
  address payable public owner;

struct People {
    uint256 uuid;
    string name;
    string lastname;
}

struct Image {
    uint256 uuid;
    string url;
}

People[] peoples;
Image[] picture;

mapping(uint256 => bool) _peopleExists;
```

This is actually compiling and working, but I don't know if it does what I'm expecting:
and Erc721 signed by two people.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you expect from that? It seems the only link between an NFT and the two people is `_mint(msg.sender, _id + _id2);`.

Comment: @Ismael , I just want to create a ERC721 token signed by two people (with two owners, "multisignature") and add an Image on it. And pay for that to the Owner of the contract.

Comment: The main issue here is that [EIP 721](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-721) only allow a single address to own a NFT. Without much thinking perhaps you can mark the contract as owner `_mint(address(this), _tokenId)` and have something like `mapping (_tokenId => People[2])` that allows mapping to real owners. Then add functions that accept the signatures to actions like transfer, `transfer(recipient, tokenId, signature)`.

Comment: @Ismael thanks for your answer. You give me a clue and I can continue with it. Sorry for the delay.